# Was Nebuchadnezzar's golden image a foreshadow to the image of the beast?

Tags: eschatology

God revealed a lot about the end times through the prophet Daniel during the Babylonian exile. The first revelation about the **eternal future kingdom of Christ** is shown to the king via a dream where the king saw a statue with different metals in different sections of the body and then the king sees a rock cut with **no human hand** that crashed the end times kingdoms of men, of course the head of gold was **Babylon** then the chest of **Silver** was the **Medo-Persian** empire, the thighs of **Bronze** was the **Macedonian empire**, the legs of iron was **Rome** and the feet which was a mixture of clay and iron is the **current world order** where there are weak and strong nations.

Then the king being moved by the statue in his dream decided to build a golden image and ordered all his subjects to worship it, anyone who defied this command was to be killed by being thrown into the furnace of fire.

In the book of Revelation, there is a similar test based on worship where there is an earth beast that causes the inhabitants of the earth to make an image to an earlier beast called the sea beast and also here, there is an order similar to that Nebuchadnezzar gave where who ever refuses to worship this image is to be put to death.

Am going to draw parallels between the two incidents.

1. In both, there are people who are loyal to God and refuse to worship the images where Daniel and his friends refused to worship Nebuchadnezzar's image and the saints also refuse to worship the earth beast image.
2. In both, there is an image made and people are ordered to worship it.
3. In both, there is a powerful king or governmental figure that has powers and orders men to be killed. In the case of Daniel it was Nebuchadnezzar, in the case of Revelation it is the Earth Beast.

My question, could this golden image scene during the Babylonian exile have been a prophecy detailing the Earth Beast scene in code?

Comment: From the perspective of whom?

Answer (score 2):

Well, it is worth noticing that the statue in Daniel ch3 v1 is measured in terms of the number "6"- that is, sixty cubits high and six cubits broad. That.in itself, could bring it under the idea that "6" represents humanity or something human.

Strictly speaking, it is too thin for its height to be a well-proportioned human figure (though perspective might make that less obvious from the ground). However, it is obviously something of human construction, and offered as a rival object of worship by a domineering human ruler. There is enough similarity there to the image of Revelation ch13 to make them at least part of the same theme.

Comment: the measurement of the image of Nebuchadnezzar is also allegorical to the number of the earth beast?

Comment: the measurement is 666 if we read it as length width height, this measurement is allegorical to the mark of the beast, why am i not surprised